# Input/Datalist Autocomplete not displaying

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have a site where I am trying to incorporate an autocomplete `input` using a dynamic `datalist`. Everything works fine except the list does not always drop down yet inspector shows the `datalist` is populated as expected.

As you're typing an entry into the `input` (textbox), after 3 characters the dropdown should appear but rarly does. You can open Inspector and see the the `datalist` did populate but it's just not displaying. As you type more characters, it may or may not appear. However, hitting backspace seems to more times than not make it appear. I have tried taking the typingTimer code out as well as the 2 character minimum code. I have even changed it into an AJAX call so I could try adding the async parameter but no luck. I am stumped.

[image: Example of dropdown]

HTML

```
<td>
    <input id="txtTerritorySub" list="dlTerritorySub" name="TerritorySub" style="width:300px;"placeholder="City/Parrish" />
    <datalist id="dlTerritorySub" style="width:auto;">
    </datalist>
</td>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtTerritorySub').bind("input", (function () {
        var typingTimer;
        var element = $(this);
        var srchStr = element.val();

        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if (srchStr.length > 2) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(getMatches(element, srchStr), 500);
        }
    }));
});

function getMatches(element, srchStr) {
    $("#dlTerritorySub").empty();
        $.post('Customer/getTerritorySubs', { 'srchStr': srchStr },
        function (result) {
            $(result).each(function (i, item) {
                $("#dlTerritorySub").append($("<option>", {
                    value: item.territoryCode,
                    text: item.territorySubName + ' (' + item.territoryName + ', ' + item.countryName + ')'
                }));
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example JSON string resulted from `getTerritorySubs` action and/or `getTerritorySubs` action method contents? What you mean "datalist not displaying"?

Comment: @Tetsuya - Example JSON string resulted from getTerritorySubs:[{"countryCode":"US","countryName":"United States","territoryCode":"AL","territoryName":"Alabama,"territorySubName":"Mobile"},'[{"countryCode":"BR","countryName":"Brazil","territoryCode":"CE","territoryName":"Ceará","territorySubName":"Quixeramobim"}]    What I meant by "datalist not displaying" is actually the dropdown is not displaying. See the image I provided in my original post. The `input` where I typed "birmingha" displays. the Autocomplete Dropdown below it does not.